# Running jar via command line : classnotfound exception on ONE desktop

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I've a java script who's running by several user and working very well.

Today, I asked another user to try the script on his desktop and he's getting a ClassNotFoundException... despite the script is perfectly the same as mine (and jar locations is also the same)

Here's the command tu launch the JAR :

```
java  -cp .;customname.jar;libs/* my.package.MyMainClass
```

And I also tried to add every jar in the libs folder separately :

```
java  -cp .;customname.jar;libs/lib.jar;libs/lib2.jar;libs/lib3.jar my.package.MyMainClass
```

And here's the error message the user is getting :

> Error: Could not find or load main class ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder

I checked the JAVA configuration and try to set him the same java version on "Path" environment variable. Same error.

As there's 6 user who can run the script and only one who's getting an error I'm sure it's a configuration issue. But what ? Classpath seems to be OK...

Many thanks for any help..

Comment: try with `java  -cp .:customname.jar:libs/* my.package.MyMainClass` using `:` as separator.

Comment: if you friend is not a windows user then you have to replace semicolon with a colon in the classpath

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but we're all on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: You must start by finding *where is* the conflicting class. If you don't know it, you may find it in two alternative ways:

- Programatically: Code this class and execute it with the same classpath (on an environment that does not suffer the problem):

  `public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        System.out.println(ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder.class. getResource("/ch/vaudoise/hp/services/listener/AutoSysReorder.class"));
  }`
- Manually, one by one: Open a command shell and execute:

  javap -cp . ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder

  javap -cp customname.jar ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder

  javap -cp libs/lib.jar ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder

  javap -cp libs/lib2.jar ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder

  ...

Try one by one every entry in the classpath until the class is found.

Once found the location of the class, open a shell in the conflicting PC and make sure that path is accessible:

`dir lib\conflicting-library-or-directory`

Also, repeat the javap test:

```
javap -cp conflicting-library-or-directory ch.vaudoise.hp.services.listener.AutoSysReorder
```

After this tests, you should have more clues to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you ! Helped me to find the issue. The user who had the issue was running from a UNC path, so the script couldn't execute well. 
He had to mount the network path so he can run the .bat script without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [ClassNotFoundException despite class in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595718/classnotfoundexception-despite-class-in-the-classpath)

You are also including meta character (*)  in your classpath. 
Try without that as suggested in the link.

Also some times copy pasting to command line , may get some characters copied differently.

I cannot add comment as of now : So , editing this answer.
 | Java path is not an issue.
Try the following step by step : 
  - find which jar the class that is being not found is in . 
  - include only that jar as cp. 
  - include only that class and try

```
java -jar that.jar
```

Also try this once
    `java -cp "*;"`

If you still got issue , probably the jar does not contain the class (You can open jar and check).

And you say script - is this single command which is failing or is it part of script ?. Using java -jar -cp , usually ignores cp.

Comment: I also tried to include every jar in the libs folder separately, but same issue...